# Post Thumbnail on Single (if elseif else)

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, single

I have the following news articles on the frontpage of a website I'm currently working on:

[image: Screenshot]

For this I'll need to write two simple PHP `if statement`s, which I've already done successfully, but on the `single.php` it gets troublesome for me.

On the frontpage I have the following to display the two news articles in the screenshot:

```
<div id="articles">
<?php query_posts('cat=45&posts_per_page=1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> <!-- Query for "System Updates" -->
    <div class="unit one-of-three system-update">
        <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { echo "<img src='/wp-content/themes/bosted-system/_/inc/images/system-update-small.png' alt='Bosted System Update'>"; } ?>

            <div class="description">
                <span class="date">System Update</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></span>
            </div>

        </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=1&posts_per_page=1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> <!-- Query for "Information" -->
    <div class="unit one-of-three info">

        <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { echo "<img src='/wp-content/themes/bosted-system/_/inc/images/information-small.jpg' alt='Bosted System Information'>"; } ?>

            <div class="description">
                <span class="date">Information</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></span>
            </div>

        </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Pretty straight forward. However, on the `single.php`-page I get a problem. I have the following:

```
<div class='banner'><?php if ( in_category("1") ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } elseif ( in_category("45") ) { echo "<img alt='Bosted System Update' class='system-update' src='/wp-content/themes/bosted-system/_/inc/images/system-update-big.png'/>"; } else { echo "<img class='system-update' alt='Bosted Information' src='/wp-content/themes/bosted-system/_/inc/images/information-big.jpg'/>"; } ?></div>
```

It's the first time I've ever had to write a statement like this, and I really can't sort it out.

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens that you think should be different?

Comment: The last `else` (`else { echo "<img class='system-update' alt='Bosted Information' src='./information-big.jpg'/>"; }`) isn't showing on the `single.php`.

Comment: `var_dump()` your conditions and make sure they are what you expect them to be. Results might be wrong or your expectations might be wrong.

Comment: Why hard code content into the template when you can hard code 2 widget areas inline and then add a featured post/page type widget so you can easily change the content.

Comment: In addition the the other comments, you should consider using `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to refactor the code in a preferred way, that's all. Logically, it seems to work. What I did is:

- I preferred `WP_Query()` for such custom query, because experienced WordPress enthusiasts like it that way ([We can learn more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts))
- I changed the hard-coding into WordPress way to get the theme directory, using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri%E2%80%8E)
- And finally, I used [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata%E2%80%8E) to reset the query what we started with `WP_Query()` in that block

So here is the new code:

```
<div id="articles">
<?php $system_updates = new WP_Query( array('cat'=>'45', 'posts_per_page'=>'1') ); //Query for "System Updates" ?>
<?php if ($system_updates->have_posts()) : while ($system_updates->have_posts()) : $system_updates->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="unit one-of-three system-update">
        <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { echo "<img src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/_/inc/images/system-update-small.png' alt='Bosted System Update'>"; } ?>

            <div class="description">
                <span class="date">System Update</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></span>
            </div>

        </article>
    </div> <!-- .system-update -->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php $information = new WP_Query( array('cat'=>'1', 'posts_per_page'=>'1') ); //Query for "Information" ?>
<?php if ($information->have_posts()) : while ($information->have_posts()) : $information->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="unit one-of-three info">

        <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { echo "<img src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/_/inc/images/information-small.jpg' alt='Bosted System Information'>"; } ?>

            <div class="description">
                <span class="date">Information</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></span>
            </div>

        </article>
    </div> <!-- .info -->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div> <!-- #articles -->
```

And about the `single.php`, I refactored the code into the same way. Just make sure that, you have a `the_post()` at the very beginning:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<div class='banner'><?php if ( in_category('1') ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } elseif ( in_category('45') ) { echo "<img alt='Bosted System Update' class='system-update' src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/_/inc/images/system-update-big.png'/>"; } else { echo "<img class='system-update' alt='Bosted Information' src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/_/inc/images/information-big.jpg'/>"; } ?></div>
```

Let's just try with these. I don't know why your code is not working...

Comment: Maybe the double quotes around the cat i.d in the conditional

Comment: I've learned quite a lot from your post. I'll give it a go!

Comment: @BradDalton: I actually din't try the code. If you have such experience, please edit the answer with the correction - you are welcome. :)